# Using CC to add multiple users from sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I can see how to CC particular emails when entered into the g - script. But I want to be able to add multiple users, based on a cell in Sheets, by using a var code to call them.

I've tried adding in a var into the CC syntax to no effect.

```
  function sendEmails() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
 var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
var subject = 'ILPA Request';
var body = row[1]; // Second column
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxx');
var copy = row[2];
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {cc: [copy]}, 
{attachments: [file]});
   }
 }
```

I'd like the email to be sent and copy the email addresses in the cell eing referenced, instead I get this error message: Cannot find method sendEmail(string,string,string,object,object). (line 16, file "321").

Comment: What does it look like if you Logger.log(copy)? What if rather than [copy] you just use copy?

Comment: @J.G. I get the same error if I use {cc: copy}, and if I use (cc: copy) I get a different error code, asking for a missing parenthetical. Same parenthetical error if I try cc: copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, the below code resolved my issue:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body, {cc: copy, attachments: [file]})
```